# Definir timezone para todos DateTime retornado do servidor

Tags: php

Estou utilizando um backend, que me retorna um `DateTime` por padrão UTC, usei a função `date_default_timezone_set` para definir o timezone de São Paulo, mas isso funcionava apenas para as horas do meu servidor local, não convertia as que eu trazia do backend.

Passei então a setar para cada DateTime object o timezone que preciso.
Ex:

```
$createdAt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
```

Existe alguma outra maneira para que todos `DateTime` venha com o fuso horário que preciso?

Comment: Não pode utilizar a função `date_default_timezone_set` também no seu backend?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o backend é de terceiros

Comment: Então é só da maneira que você fez mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se as datas vem no padrão UTC do servidor externo, não tem muito o que você fazer senão corrigindo manualmente como você fez. Vale lembrar que ao criar um objeto `DateTime` sem especificar o `TimeZone`, será considerado o atual do servidor, que pode não ser o UTC, portanto, o ideal a se fazer é:

```
$date = "01-05-2017 08:00:00";

$date = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PHP_EOL;
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/3ZKe3y).

Se o servidor já possuir um timezone definido que seja diferente do UTC, o resultado será diferente. Veja:

```
// Considerando que o timezone do servidor esteja configurado:
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$date = "01-05-2017 08:00:00";

// Data devidamente convertida de UTC para UTC-3:
$date1 = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$date1->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));

echo $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PHP_EOL;

// Data utilizando o timezone atual do servidor:
$date2 = new DateTime($date);
$date2->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));

echo $date2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PHP_EOL;
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ptmwW9).

Perceba que se o seu servidor estiver com o timezone configurado para America/Sao_Paulo, o horário final ficará errado se não passar como segundo parâmetro o timezone referente ao UTC.